# What would be the negative counterpart of a random variable's distribution?

Tags: probability, random-variables, exponential-distribution

I was studying probability theory and came across something I didn't quite understand.

Let's say that we have a random variable $X$ that is distributed according to the Exponential distribution with $\lambda = 1$ (i.e. $X \sim$ Expo($1$)).

I know that the PDF of $X$ is

$$f(x) = \lambda e^{-\lambda x} $$

but what would the distribution look like for $-X$?

Any feedback is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Your $f(x)$ hasn't got an $x$ in it!

Comment: Thanks @LordSharktheUnknown made the changes.

Comment: Is $\lambda$ really equal to $1$?

Comment: In this particular case, yes. The specific problem that I'm referring to sets $\lambda = 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $X$ has density function $f(x)$, then $-X$ has density function $f(-x)$. For
an exponential variable of mean $1$ it is incorrect to say its density
is $f(x)=e^{-x}$. Rather
$$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
e^{-x}& \text{if $x\ge0$,}\\
0& \text{if $x<0$.}
\end{cases}$$
Then the density function of $-X$ will be
$$f(-x)=
\begin{cases}
0& \text{if $x>0$,}\\
e^{x}& \text{if $x\le0$.}
\end{cases}$$